# How can I add a .git directory to a git repository?

Tags: python-3.x, git, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am doing unit tests on a python program who, for QA purposes, gets the repository name and the current commit hash from the .git in the directory

For my unit tests on that program I would like to have a dummy .git directory in the tests directory. That .git repository would have a single initialization commit and a remote that would not be used

When attempting to add a .git to my tool's repository, git seems to ignore it and indicates that there are no differences in the status and commit

How can I add the .git directory to my project repository ? Something like `tests/.git`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. It's inherently forbidden by Git.

You can store a tar or ZIP archive that contains the repository, and then have your test routine extract it to a temporary location. If you go that route, I recommend to use an uncompressed archive format, because it allows Git's own compression algorithms to work more efficient.

Comment: Alternatively: have the directory, but name it something like `_git`. Most git tools can be given the path to the `.git` directory via a command line flag (like `--git-dir` for git itself).

Answer (score 0):

I think we would need more details about what you want to achieve to provide like *the best* answer... but I think you should look at `git bundle`. You can track a bundle file and then use it to *regenerate* a git repo.